# how to make getx flutter to move to the next middleware

Tags: flutter-getx

Hi I'm using getx flutter middleware . on giving a list of middlewares to a page. How to acknowledge the end of one middleware so getx can move to the next one.

for example: homepage has two middlewares 1. first midpage 2. second midpage
on calling home page the app will redirect to first midpage. now on having finished my task in first midpage, how do i ask the app to redirect to the second midpage.

Answer (score 1):

main.dart

```
routingCallback:
      Get.find<AppService>(tag: Const.appService).routRecord,
```

app_service.dart

```
String rout = "";

void routRecord(Routing? r) {
  if (r != null) {
    if (r.current == Routes.HOME) {
      rout = Routes.HOME;
    } else if (r.isBack ?? false) {
      final pos = rout.lastIndexOf('/');
      rout = (pos != -1) ? rout.substring(0, pos) : rout;
    } else if (r.current != "") {
      rout = rout + r.current;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a path of pages that I have open in **rout**.
ie: home/user/profile
I can easily know where I am, and can easily go to another page.

ie: app_service.dart

```
  void _appListener() async {
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      _openPlayer(value);
    }, onError: (err) {
      Message.show("Error", "Something went wrong");
    });
 
    await ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((value) {
      if (value != null) _openPlayer(value);
    });
  }

  _openPlayer(String url) async {
    final id = YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(url);
    if (id != null) {
      final _routStack = rout.split('/');
      final playerIndex = _routStack
          .indexWhere((element) => element == Routes.PLAYER.substring(1));

      if (playerIndex == -1) {
        Get.toNamed(Routes.PLAYER, arguments: [
          id,
          (await FetchDetails.getDetail(id))?["title"] ?? "",
        ]);
      } else {
        final backCount = _routStack.length - playerIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < backCount; i++) {
          Get.back();
        }
        Get.toNamed(Routes.PLAYER, arguments: [
          id,
          (await FetchDetails.getDetail(id))?["title"] ?? "",
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      Message.show("Error", "invalid url");
    }
  }
```